# Method syntax causing confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def user_from_remember_token
    User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
end

def remember_token
    cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
end
```

1) I'm mostly confused with **def current_user=(user)**. What is the = for. I see that it's taking the user object as a parameter, but what is the point of the = sign.

2) Not sure why there is a ***** infront of remember_token. Can anyone explain this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=` at the end of the method name is a syntactic sugar used for methods that assign a value. Since parentheses are optional in Ruby, you can write `foo.current_user = (bar)` or `foo.current_user = bar`. Note that the latter looks more natural. Also note that you can use `attr_writer :current_user`.

You can also use `?` and `!` in method names in Ruby. By convention, the former indicates a boolean value to be returned, the latter indicates "dangerous" methods (e.g. that modify the object instead of returning a copy).

The `*` wraps whatever what passed to the method into an array. It works also when calling a method, then it unwraps an array.

The `||` is simply logical or; if the first operand evaluates to `nil` or `false`, the other will be returned. Often you may find `foo ||= "bar"`, which means that `foo` will get the value of "bar", unless it has a value (`foo = foo || "bar"`).

Ruby is a great language with lots of these kind of quirks. [Rubyist](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/) is a page worth visiting.

Comment: TLDR version `=` `?` `!` are all just legal characters in method names in ruby. Nothing special about them. Is the conventions on WHEN they are used that is more important.

Comment: `=`, `?` and `!` can be used at the end of the method name. While `irb` does not complain when declaring a method named `foo?bar`, it will remember the method as `foo?`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really answered my question! Still getting accustomed to ruby. I've heard great things about it though :)

Comment: It is a great language, quite easy to learn. There is a fantastic book about Ruby, [The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby). I greatly recommend reading it (the link documents Ruby 1.6, and it is somewhat out of date by now; but the bookstore around you should have more recent edition of it).

Answer (score 1):

`current_user=(user)` is a setter that allows you to do `something.current_user = foo`. The according getter would be `current_user` and look like

```
def current_user
  @current_user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The = sign before to current_user refer to attr_writer method.

It means

```
 def current_user=(user)
     @current_user = user
 end
```

For Ref:

```
http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html    
http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_writer
http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html
```