# how reverse a matrix object in ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, matrix

I am a beginner with Ruby. So I searched how reverse a matrix

```
1, 2, 3,  4    8, 9, 10, 11
4, 5, 6,  7 => 4, 5, 6,  7
8, 9, 10, 11   1, 2, 3,  4
```

I have tried:

```
require 'matrix'
m = Matrix[ [1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11] ]
m_rev = Matrix.build(m.row_size, m.column_size){|row|
    m.row_size.downto(0){|i|
        row = m.row(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `Matrix[*m.to_a.reverse]`:

```
m = Matrix[ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12] ]
 #=> Matrix[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
r = Matrix[*m.to_a.reverse]
 #=> Matrix[[9, 10, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Do not miss the `*`.

Comment: thanks it work so simple ^^. Without * works too. If you have some documentation on * (a pointer like C?)

Comment: @bioinfornatics it's called the "splat" operator in ruby: http://kconrails.com/2010/12/22/rubys-splat-operator/

Comment: @bioinformatics: On Ruby 1.8 it does not work without the `*`, try `m = Matrix[[1, 2], [3, 4]]; r = Matrix[m.to_a.reverse]; m.row_size == r.row_size`. `m` has 2 rows, `r` has only one. Maybe they fixed it in 1.9, I have no way to check it. About the `*`, I have once [answered a question about funny syntax in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122780/method-syntax-causing-confusion), you might find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
m_rev = Matrix.rows m.to_a.reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, except that `Matrix.build` iterates over both rows and columns:

```
m_rev = Matrix.build(m.row_size, m.column_size){|row, column|
  m[-row-1, column]
}
```

Simpler and faster:

```
m_rev = Matrix.rows(m.to_a.reverse)
# or
m_rev = Matrix[*m.to_a.reverse]
```